# Different interpretation of same-site (cross-site) in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, https, samesite

i have two subdomains sub1.domain.com and sub2.domain.com (original domain names are different).

the web page of sub1.domain.com has a button to create a cookie with same-site:strict and secure attribute and also configured a root '/img' in such a way as to load an image if there is any cookie in the request header.

In sub2.domain.com, it is page that load an image through `<img src="https://sub1.domain.com/img"/>`.

### Firefox

First i load the webpage on https://sub1.domain.com and created a cookie by pressing the button. and cookie was created. Then if a load the https://sub2.domain.com on firefox the code `<img src="https://sub1.domain.com/img"/>` sends the cookie correctly and the image from sub1.domain.com was loaded. But when i go to http://sub2.domain.com on firefox, i was expecting the code `<img src="https://sub1.domain.com/img"/>` to not send cookie to sub1.domain.com since http://sub2.domain.com and https://sub1.domain.com are different sites because of difference in scheme (protocol), but in firefox the cookie was send for this also and the image was loaded from https://sub1.domain.com in http://sub2.domain.com.

### Chrome

But when i did the same in chrome, after creating the cookie for https://sub1.domain.com and loading image using `<img src="https://sub1.domain.com/img"/>` in https://sub2.domain.com had the same result as in firefox. but when loading the image of sub2.domain.com in https://sub2.domain.com the cookie was not sent (i think because of the cross-site) and image was not loaded.

Can anyone explain this difference in behavior

#### Update

I found about a configuration in firefox called network.cookie.sameSite.schemeful. it was set to false value as default. I changed it to true expecting change in behavior in firefox to match that of chrome that is accessing image from https://sub1.domain.com inside http://sub2.domain.com will result in image not being loaded since they are different sites (schemefulsites).. But the result in firefox didn't change

[image]